# Can't get image to insert in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make my program so that when the snowing button is clicked the program starts loading in snowflake images on top of the photo and for some reason I cannot even get the button click function to work.  I would appreciate any  help.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<button type="button" id ="button1">Snowing</button>
<button type="button" id ="button2">Stop</button>
<div id = "div1"><img src="http://static.boredpanda.com/blog/wp-content/uuuploads/winter-landscapes/winter-landscapes-20.jpg"; height="500"; width="700"></img></div>
<img src="http://www.clipartkid.com/images/204/simple-christmas-snowflake-icon-png-clipart-image-iconbug-com-IFd3i8-clipart.png" id = "sf1" height="50"; width="50;"></img>
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button1").click(function(){
        $('#div1').prepend($('<img>',{id:'sf1',src:'http://www.clipartkid.com/images/204/simple-christmas-snowflake-icon-png-clipart-image-iconbug-com-IFd3i8-clipart.png'}))
    });
    $("#button2").click(function(){

    });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have no element with id `theDiv`. Did you mean `$('#div1')`?

Comment: You also don't appear to have jQuery included in the page

Comment: ... or a `<body>` tag

Comment: Im sorry yes I did

Comment: Also, `<img>` tags are self-closing; there is no `</img>`

Comment: You also have semi-colons after the attributes in your `<img>` tags. That is not correct either

Comment: I just adjusted the code to fix a few mistakes

Comment: Can you make your requirement clearer. Prepend just adds the new img tag right before the existing img tag. I'm guessing that's not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This should hopefully get you going in the right direction, there are a lot of mistakes with your HTML and JavaScript - an IDE might help highlight these for you.

HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="button1">Snowing</button>
<button type="button" id="button2">Stop</button>
<div id="div1">
  <img src="http://static.boredpanda.com/blog/wp-content/uuuploads/winter-landscapes/winter-landscapes-20.jpg" height="500" width="700">
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#button1').click(function() {
    $('#div1').prepend('<img src="http://www.clipartkid.com/images/204/simple-christmas-snowflake-icon-png-clipart-image-iconbug-com-IFd3i8-clipart.png">');
});
```

The main issue with your javascript is that you did `.prepend($('<img>'` instead of `.prepend('<img>'`.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/Lo74o6sh/2/

Comment: I implemented your suggestions and the code is still not working on my end.  Did I implement the jQuery wrong or something of that sort?